# Error trying to load gem middleman-bootstrap-navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, middleman

I am using middleman static website generation gem to develop a website. I want to include the bootstrap navbar into index file so i installed middleman-bootstrap-navbar gem.

Here is my **`config.rb`**

```
configure :development do
  activate :livereload
  activate :bootstrap_navbar
  ready do
  sprockets.import_asset 'bootstrap.js'
end
configure :build do
 end
```

Here is my **`gemfile`**

```
# Middleman Gems
gem 'middleman', '>= 4.0.0'

# Live-reloading plugin
gem 'middleman-livereload'

gem 'middleman-compass', '>= 4.0.0'

# Navigation
gem 'middleman-bootstrap-navbar'
gem "sass"
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.3.6", :require => false 
gem 'sass-rails', '>=3.2'
gem "jquery-middleman" #Don't forget to run 'bundle install'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~>3.0.0'
```

Here is my **`all.js`**

```
//= require jquery  
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require tree .
```

Here is my **`site.css.sass`**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "normalize";
@import "bootstrap";
@charset "utf-8";
```

I Run bundle install after installing all necessary gems and restarted my server at LiveReload ip `bundle exec middleman`. I got this error afterwards:

[screenshot of the error in mysysgit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIaT.png)

I can see require command must be the problem but I have looked up all questions in this forum but none could help me. please help.

**PS:** *Sorry I couldnt paste the error code here. That feature is not enabled in mysysgit bash.*

Comment: can you try `rails c`, the error should show up as well (and maybe be more descriptive)

Comment: raised the issue with middleman-bootstrap-navbar github repo owner (manuelmeurer) and he said it is an issue with bundler 1.11.2 which he has not yet known what really causes it. [Issue #3](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/middleman-bootstrap-navbar/issues/3)

Comment: oh, wow, that's a freak bug!